# Finding the row before maximum value using R

Tags: r, max

I'm interested in finding the row before the max value in R. The dataframe looks like this:

```
    timeround   n
1   01:00   11
2   02:00   6
3   03:00   4
4   04:00   4
5   05:00   7
6   06:00   22
7   07:00   63
8   08:00   142
9   09:00   155
10  10:00   220
11  11:00   143
12  12:00   98
13  13:00   111
14  14:00   115
15  15:00   129
16  16:00   128
17  17:00   102
18  18:00   90
19  19:00   108
20  20:00   92
21  21:00   90
22  22:00   102
23  23:00   44
24  24:00   20
```

Currently I'm able to show the max value, using:

```
with(tweetcount, timeround[n== max(n)])
```

giving me the value "10:00"

How do I compute R to give me the value before the max value - in this case "9:00"?

Comment: @akrun beat me  to it

Comment: Since it looks like you're working with data over a 24 hour period, it might be worth pointing out that if the maximum value is at "01:00", you'll get an empty data.frame with this approach rather than 24:00. Not sure if that's a problem for you or not.

Comment: That’s a good point @ping - but it is highly unlikely that it will ever be 01:00 that will hold the max value. I suppose it could be solved with an ‘if function’ – but again not necessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `which`

```
with(tweetcount, timeround[which(n== max(n))-1])
```

If there is only a single `max` value

```
 tweetcount$timeround[which.max(tweetcount$n)-1]
```

Comment: Will do - but I have to wait another 5 minutes ;)